# Setting up an image array using splice

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have set up a simple image array and want to ensure that each image from the array is used only once.  I am new to javascript and am not sure how to implement the splice element.

A link to the full site: http://p3.katecooperuk.com

Here is my javascript array:

```
var calendarImg = [
    "url(/images/tree.jpg)", 
    "url(/images/santa.jpg)", 
    "url(/images/stockings.jpg)",
    "url(/images/snoopy.jpg)",
    "url(/images/stockings2.jpg)",
    "url(/images/bear.jpg)",
    "url(/images/penguins.jpg)",
    "url(/images/baubles.jpg)",
    "url(/images/polarbear.jpg)",
    "url(/images/village.jpg)",
    "url(/images/village2.jpg)",
    "url(/images/nativity.jpg)",
    "url(/images/santa2.jpg)",
    "url(/images/snowman.jpg)",
    "url(/images/snow.jpg)",
    ]

    function imgRandom(imgArr) {
        return imgArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArr.length)];
    }

$('.doors').click(function(){ 

    // Select Random Image
    var doorImage = imgRandom(calendarImg); 

    // Change background image of door that was clicked
    $(this).css('background-image', doorImage); 

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to know more about splice, visit this [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

```
function getRandomImage(arr) {
    if (arr.length > 0) { 
        random = Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)
        return arr.splice(random, 1)[0];
    } 
}
```

This function would return you an element from the array and delete that element from the array. So, every time you call the function, you get back an unique element until the array is empty.

If the array is empty, the function returns `undefined`.

If there is anything more regarding the implementation, ask away.

Comment: Thanks Arijit, I appreciate it, I'm very new to js.  If I were to use your function, how would I set up my array?

Comment: Thanks Arijit and Wared, it's working perfectly.  Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is almost correct. Please try:

```
$('.doors').bind('click',function(){ 
     // Select Random Image
    var doorImage = imgRandom(calendarImg); 

    // Change background image of door that was clicked
    $(this).css('background-image', doorImage); 
}
```

Also improve your random function:

```
function imgRandom(imgArr) {
        var return_item = imgArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArr.length)];
        if (imgArr.length > 0) { 
           calendarImg = [];
           var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*imgArr.length);
           calendarImg = imgArr.splice(random, 1);
        } 

        return return_item;

}
```

Comment: thank you Vijay, this works but the images are still being used more than once

Comment: How would I set it up so the images were only used once?

Comment: @user3051659  Please check I have edited my answer.. hopefully it will work for you.